# Cannot display Dimension Extended Data Types in SSRS from AX 2009

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, microsoft-dynamics

If you use the built in query (EmplTableListPage) from AX2009 and try to build an SSRS report with it and you use the field Dimension[1] (or any dimension field for that matter), the report preview in Visual Studio 2008 will render correctly. After you deploy the report to the SSRS server, it will fail to load with an error similar to:

```
 An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'Dataset1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
The AX query string 'SELECT EmplTable.1.Dimension[1],EmplTable.1.EmplId,DirPartyTable.1.Name FROM EmplTableListPage' is invalid. The valid format is 'SELECT [fields] FROM [AX query name]', where [fields] can be either '*' or a comma separated field list.
```

If you remove the Dimension[1] field from the report and re-deploy the error goes away and the report renders correctly.

I have tried adding a field to the query in the AOT and adding Dimension[1] specifically but that did not work either (same error message).

How do I display data from the Dimension fields in SSRS reports? and why does it work in Visual Studio but not in AX or the Report Manager Website?

Comment: Found this:[What's new in AX 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg724100.aspx), describing that dimensions aren't supported in AX 2009 SSRS. Is this a fact? Has anyone found a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft in their [What's New in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg724100) whitepaper, 2012 was enhanced to support dimensions which were not supported in AX 2009 meaning that you can not display data from dimension fields on SSRS reports:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used this kind of approach (joining all posible Dimensions table combinations) note that example is only for first two dmensions:
[image: LedgerTransSRS query]

Than from ssrs:

```sql
SELECT LedgerTable.1.AccountName,Dimensions.1.DimensionCode:NAME(SysDimension),Dimensions.2.DimensionCode:NAME(SysDimension) FROM LedgerTransSRS
```

By the way my original Query name was not LedgerTransSRS, my original Query name was LedgerTransSRS_companySufix I erased the _companySufix for this example. So do not modify original LedgerTransSRS query (because it`s exists in and is being used in SYS layer).

Comment: This would work if the dimensions being used are stored in a different table, but not if the dimensions are a stored array field on a table, like EMPLTable.dimension[1].

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem but was able to resolve it.
When you add the data set in SSRS you must add all fields in the dimension (your query has the dimension listed in fields) - and not just the field of the dimension that you want to access.

So the query for the dataset in ssrs should be:

```
SELECT * FROM EmplTable
```

The part of your query that is causing the error is: `EmplTable.1.Dimension[1]`

Get all the fields in your query in the dataset in SSRS and it should solve the problem.

Comment: This is from a standard query that is built into AX. EMplTableListPage has all of the fields of EMPLTable in the query. If I create an SSRS report with the report builder it will run your query above. If you try and use Visual Studio to incorporate business logic and import to AX it fails. The report preview in Visual Studio handles the query as well. It only fails when it is run from AX.